# Call a custom form in node template

Tags: forms, 8

Following the Form generation example from DrupalAPI (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/form_api/8.1.x), I have an error when I call the form in my template_preprocess_node.

Here's my code.

#### mymodule/src/Form/ExampleForm.php

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class ExampleForm extends FormBase {
  public function getFormId() {
    // Unique ID of the form.
    return 'example_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Create a $form API array.
    $form['phone_number'] = array(
      '#type' => 'tel',
      '#title' => $this->t('Your phone number')
    );
    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Validate submitted form data.
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Handle submitted form data.
  }
}
```

#### mytheme/mytheme.theme

```
function cmimmo_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['simulator_form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(\Drupal\mymodule\Form\ExampleForm::class);
}
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The form argument Drupal\mymodule\Form\ExampleForm is not a valid form. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->getFormId() (line 190 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder.php).

Why am I getting that error message? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you try to call your form without ::class ?

Comment: Already did, didn't work :(

Comment: this is how i call my form into a block : \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\boutique\Form\PanierForm'); the main diff is the \ before Drupal

Comment: $variables['simulator_form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\nhsimulator\Form\ExampleForm'); I got the exact same error. Really I don't know why :(

Comment: I'm an idiot... The src/Form folder whas named "Forms". -__- Kill me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Form folder in my module was named "Forms". Be carefull with your file structure. Too bad the error is not very explicit. It should be "not exist" instead of "not valid".

Comment: Ran into the same issue, very similiar idiot mistake. For other that may stumble onto this ensure that your form folder is placed under /my_module/src/Form and then namespaced Drupal\my_module\Form, as opposed to being located at /my_module/form